# Conflict between Omega and Views 3 exposed sort (Ajaxified)

Tags: 7, theming, views

I have made a subtheme out of the Omega 4 with the responsive structure.
I tried to use exposed sort for views inside the layouts of the subtheme.

The exposed sorts are not working under the activation of AJAX inside the views, but the exposed filters are working.

Any recommendations?!

Comment: I need to use them with AJAX! but the exposed sorts are not really working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it seems to be a database problem for Drupal, and nothing to do with Theme or Views!

---

> Just remove that specific view from the layout inside your Panel/Page
>   design in Pages section, and add it another time.

---

It will update the Drupal database and everything starts to work!

Answer (score 0):

- This Issue may come from **Omega's responsive grid** Try Deactivating it.
- Check this [Link](https://www.drupal.org/node/1271056) which replicates your question

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have actually read it previously and the only issue is that I have to keep the responsive design as its a requirement for the current project I'm doing. I was only looking for other ideas inside here, as I explored the ideas in drupal.org

Comment: I found the solution and have updated both my post and Drupal.org post.

Comment: That's cool !!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Views theme file with the original, that you get from Views.

For me; copying `views-view.tpl`, to my custom theme (e.g. `views-view--locations--contact-us.tpl`) helped to solve the issue.